# Partial flight of a particle off a table

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

This is an experiment I need help with. A particle rolls from the top of a ramp of length L from a height h above a desk, and which makes an acute angle $\theta$ with the desk.[image]

It then falls from the edge of the ramp off the desk, which has a height of H. I measured the horizontal displacement x of the particle from the base of the desk.

How do I obtain x as a function of h, in terms of L, H, and g?

I've got the velocity off the edge of the table as $V=\sqrt{2gh}$.

Treating the end of the ramp as the origin I've also got the parametric equations $x(t)=Vt\cos(\theta)$ and $y(t)=H-Vt\sin(\theta)-0.5gt^2$, but when I solve these I get this:
[image]

I feel like I've made a mistake, especially since this doesn't align well with the experimental data. It could just be something wrong with the experiment though; are there any major errors I could have made?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: A rolling particle picks up rotational kinetic energy as well as translational kinetic energy which would mean that the speed at which the particle left the ramp would be less that $\sqrt{2gh}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a *sphere rolling without slipping* one needs to take into account the **rotational kinetic energy** as well as the translational one:

$$\Delta K=\frac12 mv^2+\frac12 I\omega^2$$

(If we assume at $h$ the sphere was stationary).

For a uniform sphere:

$$I=\frac25 mR^2$$

And for rolling without slipping:

$$\omega=\frac{v}{R}$$

$$\implies \Delta K=\frac12 mv^2+\frac12 \frac25 mR^2\Big(\frac{v}{R}\Big)^2$$
$$=\Big(\frac12+\frac15\Big)mv^2=\frac{7}{10}mv^2$$
This then is equal to the change in potential energy (assuming no rolling losses, of course):

$$\Delta U=mgh=\frac{7}{10}mv^2\implies v=\sqrt{\frac{10}{7}gh}$$

Since as this is a smaller value than what you were using, this *may* explain your discrepancy.